# Run pre-command with .NET Installer

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, installation

I have a simple command line command that I need to run as the first action when my installer opens, before pre-reqs are checked.  I'm using the built in .NET Installer with .NET 3.5 and c#.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing to do is set it up so the users start a batch that runs your command line command first and the installer second.  If needed you can bundle them both together in a self-extracting zip file that is configured to run the batch file on unzip.

Comment: Yep, that's what we do currently, but I'd like to skip the need to bundle into the self extracting zip.